# Where to place attribution details for Emojis in blog posts (CC BY 4.0)?

Tags: attribution, cc-by

I'm writing blog posts and would like to include Emojis.

I found [Emojis](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) which are licensed by CC BY 4.0.

[This article](https://www.pixsy.com/academy/image-user/correctly-attribute-images/) says (highlighting by me):

> To make sure images are correctly attributed, include the following details and **make sure they are clearly displayed by the relevant image (ideally directly underneath)**: [...]

Giving attribution for each Emoji directly underneath the Emoji or even adding a footnote to each Emoji is a bit awkward as it interrupts the reader's flow.

Ideally, I'd like to have one attribution page on my blog where I state which Emojis are used in my blog posts and give the attribution there.

[This creativecommons website](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-insist-on-the-exact-placement-of-the-attribution-credit) says:

> For example, providing attribution to the creator when using licensed material in a blog post may be different than doing so in a video remix.

It doesn't say what the exact difference is though.

What is the correct way to give attribution for Emojis in blog posts (for CC BY 4.0)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creative Commons also has a [wiki page with some best practices for attributing](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution). On that page they say among other things

> #### Don't make it too complicated
>
> The license tells you to be reasonable:
>
> > You may satisfy the conditions in (1) and (2) above in any **reasonable manner** based on the medium, means and context in which the Licensed Material is used. For example, it may be reasonable to satisfy some or all of the conditions by retaining a copyright notice, or by providing a URI or hyperlink associated with the Licensed Material, if the copyright notice or webpage includes some or all of the required information.
>
> There is no one right way; just make sure your attribution is reasonable and suited to the medium you're working with. That being said, you still have to include attribution requirements somehow, even if it's just a link to an About page that has that info. (More on different mediums below.)

Expecting that you place attribution and licensing information next to each emoji you use would not be reasonable.

If your blog has a footer with copyright information, I would make a short mention there that the emojis are from another source and then link to a licensing page with the full attribution information. And make that page easy to find, even if you don't have such a footer or people don't think about looking there for a link.

Most attribution guidelines don't take such small items as emojis into account and give their advise based on images that are at least as high as half a dozen lines of text. Then it is quite reasonable to have the attribution in the caption or otherwise on the same page.

Answer (score 4):

The README of the GitHub project you linked [has an "Attribution requirements" section](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji#attribution-requirements):

> As an open source project, attribution is critical from a legal, practical and motivational perspective in our opinion. The graphics are licensed under the CC-BY 4.0 which has a pretty good guide on [best practices for attribution](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Best_practices_for_attribution).
>
> However, we consider the guide a bit onerous and as a project, will accept a mention in a project README or an 'About' section or footer on a website. In mobile applications, a common place would be in the Settings/About section (for example, see the mobile Twitter application Settings->About->Legal section). We would consider a mention in the HTML/JS source sufficient also.

This is similar to the guidance in [Bart van Ingen Schenau's answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/9743) and suggests an acknowledgement in the footer of your website is sufficient.